# SKMaps OpenSourceDemo crashing

Tags: android, openstreetmap, skmaps

Just downloaded `SKMaps` Android `SDK` and demo. The demo app is crashing with following:

```
04-28 09:51:12.891: E/Adreno-ES11(22284): <qglDrvAPI_glDeleteTextures:371>: GL_INVALID_VALUE                             
04-28 09:51:12.897: A/libc(22284): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000074 (code=1), thread 22322 (Thread-7847)             
04-28 09:52:07.843: E/Adreno-ES11(22486): <qglDrvAPI_glDeleteTextures:371>: GL_INVALID_VALUE                                
04-28 09:52:07.853: A/libc(22486): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000074 (code=1), thread 22529 (Thread-7859)
```

Development environment: Eclipse, Android 4.4.2, Device MotoG. (There is supposed to be an skmaps tags for all Skobbler related questions. I can't find any such tag). Note that I made following changes in SplashActivity.java in function prepareMapCreatorFile. I believe this is
a valid change.

```
    //final String mapCreatorFolderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/SKMaps";                            
    //
    final String mapCreatorFolderPath;                                                                               
    if (isExternalStorageWritable()) {                                                                               
            mapCreatorFolderPath = getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/SKMaps";                          
    } else {                                                                                                         
            mapCreatorFolderPath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/SKMaps";                                      
    } 


    /* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */                                                 
    private boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {                                                                    
            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();                                                    
            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {                                                           
                    return true;                                                                                     
            }                                                                                                        
            return false;                                                                                            
    }
```

Comment: the tag should be [skmaps] (I've added it myself)

Comment: try another Android phone as I'm not sure they've tested on a MotoG and could be something particular to that hardware/software combination

Comment: (disclaimer: I'm developing with skmaps) - the test team was not able to reproduce this issue so you should contact support directly dev@skobbler.com

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was deleting the app and reinstalling it, so assets where copied again, and then it suddenly worked :X